# Regex match last word in string ending in

Tags: regex

I want to regex match the last word in a string where the string ends in `...` The match should be the word preceding the `...`

Example: "Do not match this. This sentence ends in the last word..."

The match would be `word`. This gets close: `\b\s+([^.]*)`. However, I don't know how to make it work with only matching `...` at the end.

This should NOT match: "Do not match this. This sentence ends in the last word."

Comment: `(\S+)\.\.\.$` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\s+` it means there must be at least a single whitespace char preceding so in that case it will not match `word...` only.

If you want to use the negated character class, you could also use

```
([^\s.]+)\.{3}$
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s.]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or dot
- `)` Close group
- `\.{3}` Match 3 dots
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v7AlhI/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor your regex to the end with `$`. To match a literal period you will need to escape it as it otherwise is a meta-character:

```
(\S+)\.\.\.$
```

`\S` matches everything everything but space-like characters, it depends on your regex flavor what it exactly matches, but usually it excludes spaces, tabs, newlines and a set of unicode spaces.

You can play around with it here:

https://regex101.com/r/xKOYa4/1